# Resize tables left to right in a mobile view

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having a an issue which I think it's conceptually really simple but I can't seem to nail it using CSS.

I want to stack two tables on a mobile view, from  left to right, so the left table moves below the right, rather than the default right table falling down underneath the left table.

I've tried `float:clear`..but maybe I'm not doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this only this way:

**HTML**

```
<table class="right"></table>
<table class="left"></table>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .right { float:right; width:49%; }

@media screen and (max-width:320px){
  .right, .left { float:none; width:100%; }
}
```

The left table has to be first in HTML (use `float:right` to position them like you want on default screen size, and `float:none` on mobile screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If older browser support is not an issue, you can use css3 [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) layout model.

Apply the following to parent element which contains both tables

```
#container {
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Kwz/2/) (*resize the output window to see it work*)

More about flexboxes @ [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)